# How to group users to give similar file permissions to each user in the group

Tags: linux, permissions, users, group

I have 2 users `user1` and `user2` in my Ubuntu PC. `user1` was the one I created during installation. I created `user2` to execute a python program. Now, this program is present in the path `/home/user1/programs/`. So, `user2` is executing a program located in the home directory of `user1`. During the execution, I'm unable to create files inside the output directory `/home/user1/programs/Output/`. So, I went ahead to check the permissions and found the following:

```
$ ls -l /home/user1/programs/
drwxrwxr-x 10 user1 user1 4096 Sep  6 11:30 Output
drwxrwxr-x  2 user1 user1 4096 Sep  5 17:50 source

$ cd Output

$ mkdir dummy1

$ ls -l
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1  user1  4096 Sep  6 11:30 dummy1

$ cd dummy1

$ vi a.txt

$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 7 Sep  6 11:31 a.txt

$ cd ..

$ sudo mkdir dummy2

$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  6 12:37 dummy2
```

It's clear that other users like `user2` don't have `write` permissions within the `home` directory of `user1`.

Now, I want to add the users `user1` and `user2` into the same group with same permissions so that `user2` can get a `rwx (7)`? How to create such a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo -i
addgroup mygroup
addgroup user1 mygroup
addgroup user2 mygroup
chgrp -R mygroup /home/user1/programs/Output/
chmod -R ug+rwX  /home/user1/programs/Output/
find /home/user1/programs/Output/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +
exit
```

This adds a group called `mygroup`, adds both users to that group, and changes the group-ownership of `/home/user1/programs/Output/` (and all files & sub-directories) to `mygroup`.

It and then sets the permissions of the directory to read, write, execute and all files in it to allow read and write. Again, this is applied recursively to all sub-directories of `../Output/`

Finally it sets the setgid bit on the directories with `chmod g+s` so that all files and sub-directories created underneath `/home/user1/programs/Output/` will be in `mygroup`.

All of this needs to be done as root, hence the `sudo -i` to start a root shell first and the `exit` at the end to quit the root shell.

Comment: Looks neat. Trying this out now. Any possible negative side-effects if I add the entire home directory of both users (by doing steps 5 and 6 for `user1` and `user2`)? Just being curious.

Comment: no side-effect, but the **effect** will be that user1 and user2 will have full read and write access to each other's files and sub-directories (including ~/mail, ~/.gnupg, ~/.ssh/ and everything else.  actually ssh and gnupg would probably complain about permissions, by default they're fussy about perms).  I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: If a file in `/home/user1/programs/Output/` has a description of `drwxrwxr-x`, won't adding `user1` and `user2` to mygroup automatically give `user2` write and execute access?

Comment: yes, if the file is is owned by group mygroup and both those users are in that group.   All the chmod + chgrp stuff in my answer is to ensure that that is the case for that directory.